# How to dump database from mysql with sensitive data removed or corrupted?

Tags: mysql, security

I am using mysql. Some of the tables contain sensitive data like user names, email addresses, etc. I want to dump the data but with these columns in the table removed or modified to some fake data. Is there any way to do it easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using this approach:

1. Copy contents of sensitive tables to a temporary table.
2. Clear/encrypt the sensitive columns.
3. Provide `--ignore-table` arguments to mysqldump.exe to leave the original tables out.

It preserves foreign key contraints, and you can keep columns that are not sensitive.

The first two actions are contained in a stored procedure that I call before doing the dump. It looks something like this:

```
BEGIN 
    truncate table person_anonymous;
    insert into person_anonymous select * from person;

    update person_anonymous              set Title=null, Initials=mid(md5(Initials),1,10), Midname=md5(Midname), Lastname=md5(Lastname), Comment=md5(Comment);
END
```

As you can see, I'm not clearing the contents of the fields. Instead, I keep a hash. That way, you can still see which rows have the same value, and between exports you can see if something changed or not, without anyone being able to read the actual values.

Comment: It's a bit complex. Especially when the table is large, the table copy and the update would be resource consuming. Thanks for the solution anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called [Jailer](http://jailer.sourceforge.net/) that is typically used to export a subset of a database. We use this at work to create a smaller test database from a production backup, with all sensitive data obfuscated.

The GUI is a bit crude, but Jailer is the best alternative I have found so far.
You can simply unselect the sensitive tables or columns and get a full copy of the rest. Jailer also supports obfuscating data during export - you could for instance md5 hash all user names or change all email addresses to user@example.org.

There is a [tutorial](http://jailer.sourceforge.net/exporting-data.htm) to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

ProxySQL is another approach.

Here is an article explaining how to obfuscate data with proxysql.

https://proxysql.com/blog/obfuscate-data-from-mysqldump

Comment: interesting concept